# R Apply function on data frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, numeric

I have a function in R to turn factors to numeric:

```
    as.numeric.factor <- function(x) {as.numeric(levels(x))[x]}
```

and I have a dataframe that consists of both factors, numeric and other types of data.
I want to apply the functions above at once on the whole dataframe to turn all factors to numeric types columns.
Any idea ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be:

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.numeric(levels(x))[x] else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check whether the column is `factor` or not by `is.factor` and `sapply`.  Use that as an index to filter out those columns and convert the columns to "numeric" by `as.numeric.factor` function in a `lapply` loop.

```
indx <- sapply(dat, is.factor)
dat[indx] <- lapply(dat[indx], as.numeric.factor)
```

You could also apply the function without subsetting (but applying it on a subset would be faster)

To prevent the columns to be converted to "factor", you could specify `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` argument or `colClasses` argument within the `read.table/read.csv`  I would imagine the columns to have atleast a single non-numeric component which automatically convert this to `factor` while reading the dataset.